# Remove white-spacing but keep paragraphs

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to write a code which removes all white spaces but keeps paragraphs instead.

I have this code:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', "1st.     line
2nd.      line goes here

3rd. line   goes   there");

echo $replaced;
```

As an output I get:

```
1st. line 2nd. line goes here 3rd. line goes there
```

But it should be like this:

```
1st. line 
2nd. line goes here 

3rd. line goes there
```

nl2br() function isn't a good solution for me, because I need to put this output in a textarea.

Comment: Do you get that output in a browser or on CLI? If in browser view the source or place the output in `<pre></pre>` or a textarea as needed. Browsers won't show `\n` as linebreaks on a page

Comment: I getting that output in browser and I'd like to get the same output in a browser with line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/[\\t\' \']+/` this will remove tabs and spaces

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will not show `\n` as linebreaks on a page. Either view the source of the page to make sure the output is as desired or place your output inside `<pre></pre>` or `<textarea></textarea>`:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', "1st.     line
2nd.      line goes here

3rd. line   goes   there");

echo "<textarea>{$replaced}</textarea>";
```